# Rails 3.1 :after_remove association callback not firing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, callback

I have the following models using single table inheritance:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class ContainerTest < Test
has_many :subtests, :class_name => 'Test', :foreign_key => 'container_test_id', :before_remove => :delete_if_without_subtests

def delete_if_without_subtests(task)
  ...
end

class BasicTest < Test
end
```

I'm expecting the `delete_if_without_subtests` method to be called whenever an association between a `ContainerTest` and a `BasicTest` is removed, but this isn't happening. If I substitute `:before_add` in place of `:before_remove`, the callback is issued, but that's of no use.

I realize I could put this into the `BasicTest` model, but it doesn't relate to `BasicTest`s, and it really is more about the association than the model, since changing a `BasicTest`'s association to another `ContainerTest` should also trigger this method.

Why isn't the method registered to `:before_remove` being called?

Comment: rails haven't `before_remove`, especially in has_many. Maybe you need one of them: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#destroying-an-object

Comment: @IgorKapkov Yes it does, check [Associations callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Association+callbacks).

Comment: Jordan, how do you call this remove method? Make sure you call it on association and not on an associated object.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I think you need `:dependent => :restrict`, this mean this object cannot be deleted if it has any associated object.

Comment: there is no `:dependent => :restrict` option in ActiveRecord. Only `:delete—all`, `:destroy`, `:nullify`.  Are you referring to some gem which adds this functionality? Or do you mean setting it directly in the database?